# How do I print the evaluated condition instead of its boolean value in python?

Tags: python, operators, conditional-statements, argparse

Assuming '--run' is provided as an argument, how do I declare the 'opt.run' condition in a variable, instead of it's boolean value using an 'or' series operation?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--pre",dest="pre",action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("--run",dest="run",action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("--post",dest="post",action="store_true")
opt = parser.parse_args()

step = opt.pre or opt.run or opt.post
```

Printing 'step' results in 'True', but what I really need is the condition that evaluates 'True' - i.e. 'opt.run'.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is something like:

```
 step = "pre" if opt.pre else "run" if opt.run else "post" if opt.post else "default"
 print(step)
```

If you had logic that the user had to choose one of the three you could drop the last if:

```
 step = "pre" if opt.pre else "run" if opt.run else "post"
```

But I would recommend breaking it up into if/elif's:

```
step = "default"
if opt.run:
    step = "run"
elif opt.pre:
    step = "pre"
elif opt.post:
    step = "post"
```

Comment: Thanks Padraic, was hoping for a one-liner but went with your suggestion after all. A good reminder that 'elegant' doesn't always mean 'better'.